# Why does opening a file in utf 8 mode change the behaviour of seek?

Tags: perl, file, utf-8, seek

Here's a simple text file with no special characters, called `utf-8.txt` with the following content.

```
foo bar baz
one two three
```

The new line is following the unix convention (one byte), so that the entire size of the file is 26 = 11 + 1 + 13 + 1. (11 = `foo bar baz`, 13 = `one two three`.

If I read the file with the following perl script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $f, '<', 'utf8.txt');
<$f>;
seek($f, -4, 1);
my $xyz = <$f>;
print "$xyz<";
```

it prints

```
baz
<
```

This is expected, since the `seek` command goes back four characters, the new line and the three belonging to `baz`.

If I now change the `open` statement to

```
open (my $f, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'utf8.txt');
```

the output changes to

```
 baz
<
```

that is, the `seek` command goes back five characters (or it goes back four characters but skips the new line).

Is this behaviour expected? Is there a flag or somthing to turn this behaviour off?

**Edit**

As per *Andrzej A. Filip* suggestion, when I add `print join("+",PerlIO::get_layers($f)),"\n";` just after the `open` statement, it prints in the "normal" open case: `unix+crlf` and in the `open...encoding` case: `unix+crlf+encoding(utf-8-strict)+utf8`.

Comment: Add the following test just after `open` in both scripts: `print join("+",PerlIO::get_layers($f)),"\n";`

Comment: Please see my amended question

Comment: It's related to the :crlf layer. Workaround: `open (my $f, '<', 'utf8.txt');
binmode($f);
binmode($f, ':encoding(UTF-8)');
`

Comment: (That disables the :crlf layer, but you indicated it wasn't needed.)

Comment: It helps to have the correct input file when trying to reproduce someone's output. (I have no problems reproducing the problem.)

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a **TL;DR**, *`seek` and `tell` work in bytes. `seek` should always be okay if it uses values returned by `tell`*

---

The documentation for Perl's [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) operator is rather clumsy but it has this

> **seek FILEHANDLE,POSITION,WHENCE**
>
> The values for WHENCE are 0 to set the new position in bytes to POSITION ...

and

> Note the *in bytes*: even if the filehandle has been set to operate on characters (for example by using the `:encoding(utf8)` open layer), tell() will return byte offsets, not character offsets (because implementing that would render seek() and tell() rather slow).

While this alludes to the problem it isn't stated explicitly

`seek` and `tell` use and return *byte offsets* within the file, *regardless of any other PerlIO layer*. That means they work on similar terms to [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) which is independent of Perl's streaming IO, although `seek` and `tell` respect Perl's buffering whereas `sysread` does not

It isn't just `:utf8` or `:encoding` layers that confuse what units you may expect: the Windows `:crlf` layer also has an effect because it converts CR LF pairs to LF before streaming input and after output. That clearly causes a discrepancy for every line of text, but as far as I can tell this isn't mentioned in Perl's documentation; Linux and OSX being the pushy ugly sisters of pretty much every other Perl platform

Let's look at your code. I've run this code (it's identical to the code in your question, I promise) on my Windows 10 and Windows 7 systems, and even booted a VM with Windows 98 to try the same thing

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $f, '<', 'utf8.txt');
print join("+",PerlIO::get_layers($f)),"\n";
<$f>;
seek($f, -4, 1);
my $xyz = <$f>;
print "$xyz<";
```

All of them output this

```
unix+crlf
az
```

which is what I expected, and not what you say you get. This is central since we're talking about single-byte offsets

Your file contains this

```
foo bar baz\r\none two three
```

The first read takes us to 13 characters from the start. Perl has read foo `bar baz\r\n` and removed the CR, handing `foo bar baz\n` to the program, which it discards. Fine

Now you `seek($f, -4, 1)`

That third parameter 1 is `SEEK_CUR`, which means you want to move the current read pointer *relative to the current position*.

**Please**

Please don't use magic numbers. Perl is pretty much exposing the underlying [*C file library*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) to you here and you need to be responsible with it. Passing 1 as the third parameter is arcane and irresponsible. No one who reads your code will know what you have written

Do this

```perl
use Fcntl ':seek'
```

and then you can write more intelligible code like this. At least people can google `SEEK_CUR` whereas trying the same with `1` would be worse than fruitless

```perl
seek($f, -4, SEEK_CUR)
```

as it gives the rest of us a chance to understand your code

So you're seeking to 13 bytes, add -4 which is 9. That's just after the `b` of `baz`, and so I get `az`

That's what all my runs of your code produced on all of those different Windows machines. I have to think that the problem is with your code control and not with Perl, except for the issue with CRLF

I hope that this explained some anomalies for you, but please check your code and your results.